# change error message on the log in page

Tags: magento-1.9, password

Where would i be able to find the message that appears when a customer enters a wrong password when they try to log in, I have already looked in validation.js but i couldn't find it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is processing by customer account controller `Mage_Customer_AccountController::loginPostAction()`. File location is

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

Dig from here. I think the error that is generated when password do not match in customer model. ie `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::authenticate()`. There you can see this part

File: `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`

```
 if (!$this->validatePassword($password)) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid login or password.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
 }
```

Dig more with this info